# Code changes not taking effect on Drupal site

Tags: php, caching, drupal, drupal-7

I'm sure this has been asked a dozen times here, but nothing I've found online or on here has helped. There's something strange about the Drupal site I'm currently working on - I've worked on 10+ other sites at this company with no problem - in that none of the code changes I make seem to have any effect. Anything I do through the admin backend appears immediately, but when I try to change the text in a custom page template and push it live, nothing happens.

What I know/did:

- I know I'm pushing correctly because when I go in the file manager on the live server and look at the files I pushed, the changes are present.
- I am sure that I am changing the correct file because when I try it locally and on our staging server, the corresponding pages update immediately.
- I cleared out the site's cache in the admin menu, in Configuration -> Development -> Performance -> Clear all caches.
- I asked the hosting company if there was a cache to clear on their end, they said no.
- I deleted the uploaded theme from the server completely. The theming is still present, though the images are broken links. So the site theming is still cached somewhere. (I then replaced the theme folder)
- I then contemplated quitting web development and opening an orphanage in Pakistan

What I did not do:

- I did not run root/update.php. I figured this would recache the database and that wouldn't affect text in a custom page template (I also searched for that original text in the database to make sure).

Does anyone have any other ideas I could try?

Answer (score 0):

It could be nginx cache on the server. Or PHP opcache could prevent you from seeing PHP code changes.

But if you still see deleted Drupal theme, it is rather some proxy or maybe something right in your browser instead of the server.